# My Bluetooth Receiver is receiving events only once from my AlarmManager

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I looked to many tutorials and question online regarding how to set an alarmmanager to a broadcast in order to get system events (bluetooth discovery in my case). However, I failed to achieve this for some reasons that I don't know yet.

my receiver class is as follows:

public class MyBluetoothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Calendar call = Calendar.getInstance();
    call.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Date date = call.getTime();

    Log.i("BlueTestm: ", "" + action);


    if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) 
    {
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        Log.i("\nDevice: ",  device.getName() + ", " + device + ", T: " + date.toLocaleString() );
        String t1 = "\nDevice: "+  device.getName() + ", " + device + ", T: " + date.toLocaleString();

        Toast.makeText(context, t1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) 
    {
        String t2 = "Discovery Started";
        Log.i("BlueTest: ", "" + t2);

        Toast.makeText(context, t2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) 
    {
        String t3 = "Discovery finished"; 
        Log.i("BlueTest: ", "" + t3);

        Toast.makeText(context, t3, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   
}
```

}

and I'm calling this method on my main activity:

**UPADTED:**

```
public void startAlert() {
    int i = Integer.parseInt("15");
    IntentFilter filter;

    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(blueReciver, filter);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBluetoothReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    long triggerAtTime = cal.getTimeInMillis()+ (i * 1000); // starts in 30 minutes
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (i * 1000), triggerAtTime, pendingIntent);

    //alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (i * 1000),  pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is to do bluetooth discovery every 15 seconds. After I updated my code, now the alarm works fine but my bluetooth receiver is receiving "actions" only for the first time, then  whenever the alarm triggers the receiver, the "action" string returns null on the alarm calls. From my understanding, the app is not doing any discovery from the second scan. Actually it is not doing any scanning at all after the first call. So far I'm trying to find out why is that happening.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In ur bluetooth receiver code add the bluetooth discovery code

Comment: Shouldn't my MyBluetoothReceiver receives those events?

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J you were right, I should have registered my receiver. But now it only works for the first call then it receives null action.